# EWS Managed API Bulk Mass delete failes for more than 1000 contacts

Tags: vb.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm using ews managed api 2.2 in vb.net to delete about 30000 contacts in an exchange 2013 mailbox (using impersonation)

The Contacts which will be deleted are in an list (of contact).

```
Dim lsttodelete As New List(Of Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemId)
   For Each exchangecontact In tmpexchangecontacts
        'exchangecontact.DeleteContactFromExchange()
        lsttodelete.Add(exchangecontact.OriginContact.Id)
        Contacsdeleted = Contacsdeleted + 1
        If lsttodelete.Count = 999 Then
            Try
                Exchangeservice.DeleteItems(lsttodelete, DeleteMode.HardDelete, SendCancellationsMode.SendToNone, AffectedTaskOccurrence.AllOccurrences)

                Console.WriteLine("deleted 999")

            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try

            lsttodelete.Clear()
        End If
    Next
```

However, after the first batch of 999 contacts, the deleteitems fails with an

ErrorCode ErrorInternalServerError {127} 
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceError

IF softdelete is used, 2 batches can be deleted

I've tried a sleep of 5 Minutes after the delete but the problem persists.
ThrottlingPolicies where set so nearly everything i can imagine.

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Are you trying to delete every contact in the Folder ? if so why do you use the Empty method on the Folder instead ? I'd also suggest you drop the batch size to under 100. You can also check the EWS Logs on the CAS server to see if it is throttling or not that is affecting your operation.

Comment: No, not every contact, only "a few one". Setting the Batch Size to 50 allows me to delete 20 batches.  I'll check the log files and report

Answer (score 0):

The limit is 1000 items.  Check the response body.
Its best to do such operations with 100 items.  Also, you will have less problems creating and updating things if you only do it with 10 or less each time.